# How to use UTF-8 characters in a PHP-script?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

How to use `UTF-8` characters in a PHP-script?

I know there is an escape character to interpret the next two characters as `UTF-8`. That escape is `\s`. So `\xFF` works, which will represent '`ÿ`'.
But now I want to remove zero-width spaces (`U+200B`) from a string. How to do that? Can I use the function `str_replace()`, or maybe `preg_replace()`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$str = str_replace("\xe2\x80\x8b", '', $str);
```

**Sources**:

- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm
- http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128&utf8=string-literal

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `mb_ereg_replace()` or `iconv()` with str_replace.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php
http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Answer (score -3):

Remove zero-width space:

```
$str = str_replace(chr(13), "", $str);
```

Comment: The zero-width space (ZWSP) is a specific unicode character at codepoint 200B - and UTF-8 representation E2808B.  Your solution is only affecting the single-byte sequence 13 which is inappropriate to the question.

Comment: `chr(13)` isn't a zero-width space.